# Draw the Pentaflake

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

First of all ... I would like to wish everyone a Merry Christmas (sorry if I am a day late for your timezone).

To celebrate the occasion, we are going to draw a snowflake. Because the year is 201**5** and Christmas is on the 2**5**th (for a large portion of persons), we will draw a **Penta**flake. The Pentaflake is a simple fractal composed of pentagons. Here are a few examples [(taken from here)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pentaflake.html):[image]

Each Pentaflake has an order n. The Pentaflake of order 0 is simply a pentagon. For all other orders n, a Pentaflake is composed of 5 Pentaflakes of the previous order arranged around a 6th Pentaflake of the previous order. For example, a Pentaflake of order 1 is composed of 5 pentagons arranged around a central pentagon.

## Input

The order `n`. This may be given in any way except that of a predefined variable.

## Output

An image of the order `n` Pentaflake. Must be at least 100px wide and 100px long. It may be saved to a file, displayed to the user, or outputted to `STDOUT`. Any other form of output is not allowed. All image formats existing before this challenge are allowed.

## Winning

As codegolf, the person with the least number of bytes wins.

Comment: -1 because snowflakes only have 6 fold symmetry! =D

Comment: @flawr According to [this article](http://news.sciencemag.org/environment/2013/04/scienceshot-true-shape-snowflakes?ref=hp) only about .1% of snowflakes actually have 6-fold symmetry ... or any symmetry at all. However, those snowflakes that do have symmetry can have 3-fold symmetry in addition to 6-fold symmetry :P

Comment: Well this article only studied way less than .1% of all snowflakes, and it is meaningless anyway, as they only studied american snowflakes. I bet metric snowflakes are way more symmetrical! (PS: Beautiful images! [Snowflake #167 is especially interesting](http://www.inscc.utah.edu/~tgarrett/Snowflakes/Gallery/)!) (I just noticed that metric snowflakes must have 10-fold symmetry.)

Comment: Is it necessary to have a self-contained function as an answer? I could shave off a few bytes if matlab scripts are also allowed (i.e. just a sequence of commands rather than a function). I'll edit according to this, and revert if it's not OK after all.

Comment: It will be okay as long as it outputs using one of the above methods. However, `n` cannot be predefined in your script file. You can read `n` from `STDIN`, prompt it from the user, take it as a function / commad line argument ... basically anything you want except for directly embedding it in your code.

Comment: Don't want to +1 this because it has 25 :(

Comment: Don't want to +1 this because it has 25 :(

Answer (score 16):

## Matlab, 226

```
function P(M);function c(L,X,Y,O);hold on;F=.5+5^.5/2;a=2*pi*(1:5)/5;b=a(1)/2;C=F^(2*L);x=cos(a+O*b)/C;y=sin(a+O*b)/C;if L<M;c(L+1,X,Y,~O);for k=1:5;c(L+1,X+x(k),Y+y(k),O);end;else;fill(X+x*F, Y+y*F,'k');end;end;c(0,0,0,0);end
```

Ungolfed:

```
function P(M);                
function c(L,X,Y,O);          %recursive function
hold on;
F=.5+5^.5/2;                  %golden ratio
a=2*pi*(1:5)/5;               %full circle divided in 5 parts (angles)
b=a(1)/2;
C=F^(2*L);
x=cos(a+O*b)/C;               %calculate the relative position ofnext iteration
y=sin(a+O*b)/C;
if L<M;                       %current recursion (L) < Maximum (M)? recurse
    c(L+1,X,Y,~O);            %call recursion for inner pentagon
    for k=1:5;
        c(L+1,X+x(k),Y+y(k),O)%call recursion for the outer pentagons
    end; 
else;                         %draw
    fill(X+x*F, Y+y*F,'k');  
end;
end;
c(0,0,0,0);
end
```

Fifth iteration (already took quite a while to render).

[image]

A slight alteration of the code (unfortunately more bytes) results in this beauty=)

[image]

Oh, and another one:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this challenge, I went and added another solution, hope you don't mind;) I'm safely away from your byte-count, anyway, I just found it too interesting to miss.

Answer (score 8):

### MATLAB, <strike>235</strike> <strike>233</strike> 217 bytes

**Update:** a bunch of suggestions from [**@flawr**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr) helped me lose 16 bytes. Since only this allowed me to beat [flawr's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67734/45297), and that I wouldn't have found the challenge without flawr's help in the first place, consider this a joint submission by us:)

```
N=input('');f=2*pi/5;c=1.5+5^.5/2;g=0:f:6;p=[cos(g);sin(g)];R=[p(:,2),[-p(2,2);p(1,2)]];for n=1:N,t=p;q=[];for l=0:4,q=[q R^l*[c-1+t(1,:);t(2,:)]/c];end,p=[q -t/c];end,p=reshape(p',5,[],2);fill(p(:,:,1),p(:,:,2),'k');
```

This is another MATLAB solution, this one based on a philosophy of iterated function systems. I was mostly interested in developing the algorithm itself, and I haven't golfed too much on the solution. There's surely room for improvement. (I contemplated using a hard-coded fixed-point approximation for `c`, but that wouldn't be nice.)

Ungolfed version:

```
N=input('');                                % read order from stdin

f=2*pi/5;                                   % angle of 5-fold rotation
c=1.5+5^.5/2;                               % scaling factor for contraction

g=0:f:6;
p=[cos(g);sin(g)];                          % starting pentagon, outer radius 1
R=[p(:,2),[-p(2,2);p(1,2)]];                % 2d rotation matrix with angle f

for n=1:N,                                  % iterate the points
    t=p;
    q=[];
    for l=0:4,
       q=[q R^l*[c-1+t(1,:);t(2,:)]/c];     % add contracted-rotated points
    end,
    p=[q -t/c];                             % add contracted middle block
end,

p=reshape(p',5,[],2);                 % reshape to 5x[]x2 matrix to separate pentagons
fill(p(:,:,1),p(:,:,2),'k');          % plot pentagons
```

Result for `N=5` (with a subsequent `axis equal off` for prettiness, but I hope that doesn't count byte-wise):

[image: N=5 pentaflake]

Comment: I think you could save a few bytes by using `R=[p(:,2),[-p(2,2);p(1,2)]];` (and eliminating the previous `R,C,S`) and you can use `q=[q R^l*[c-1+t(1,:);t(2,:)]/c]` and I think `c=1.5+5^.5/2;`

Comment: @flawr obviously you're right:) 1. thanks for the rotation matrix, 2. thanks for the new `q`, I even had a needless pair of parentheses in there... 3. thanks, but what is this magic??:D 4. since the solution is now shorter than your original, I consider this to be partly your submission as well.

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, 200 bytes

```
a=RotationTransform
b=Range
r@k_:={Re[t=I^(4k/5)],Im@t}
R@k_:=a[Pi,(r@k+r[k+1])/2]
Graphics@Nest[GeometricTransformation[#,ScalingTransform[{1,1}(Sqrt@5-3)/2]@*#&/@Append[R/@b@5,a@0]]&,Polygon[r/@b@5],#]&
```

The last line is a function which can be applied to an integer `n`.

Mathematica function names are long. Somebody should entropy-encode them and make a new language from it. :)

When applied to `1`:

[image]

When applied to `2`:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 124 bytes

Mathematica supports new syntax for `Table` since version 10: `Table[expr, n]`, which saves another byte.
`Table[expr, n]` is equivalent to `Table[expr, {n}]`.

```
f@n_:=(p=E^Array[π.4I#&,5];Graphics@Map[Polygon,ReIm@Fold[{g,s}~Function~Join[.62(.62g#+#&/@s),{-.39g}],p,p~Table~n],{-3}])
```

The core of this function is using complex numbers to do tranformations and then convert them to points by `ReIm`.

Test case:

```
f[4]
```

[image]

Comment: `π` takes up two bytes in UTF-8, so you come out to 125 bytes total.

Comment: OMFG what is this

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <s>199</s> 196 bytes

Edging out Peter Richter's answer by a hair, here's one of my own. It leans heavily on graphics functionality, and less on math and FP. The CirclePoints builtin is [new in 10.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html).

```
c=CirclePoints;g=GeometricTransformation;
p@0=Polygon@c[{1,0},5];
p@n_:=GraphicsGroup@{
        p[n-1],
        g[
          p[n-1]~g~RotationTransform[Pi/5],
          TranslationTransform/@{GoldenRatio^(2n-1),n*Pi/5}~c~5
        ]
      };
f=Graphics@*p
```

Edit: Thanks to DumpsterDoofus for GoldenRatio

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by replacing `((1+Sqrt@5)/2)` with `GoldenRatio`. Also in the second line I think it should be `p@0=Polygon@c[{1,0},5];` instead of `p@0=Polygon@cp[{1,0},5];`. (BTW I'm actually Peter, I've got two profiles lol).

Comment: Yes! Good call. I spotted the typo, too, but forgot to fix it. D'oh,

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 130 bytes

```
r=Exp[Pi.4I Range@5]
p=1/GoldenRatio
f@0={r}
f@n_:=Join@@Outer[1##&,r,p(f[n-1]p+1),1]~Join~{-f[n-1]p^2}
Graphics@*Polygon@*ReIm@*f
```

I use a similar technique to [njpipeorgan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68543/39174) (in fact I stole his `2Pi I/5 == Pi.4I` trick), but implemented as a recursive function.

Example usage (using `%` to access the anonymous function that was output on the last line):

```
 %[5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Wolfram Language (Mathematica), <s>96</s> <s>90</s> 84bytes

```
Region@Polygon@ReIm@Nest[Join[Tr/@Tuples@{.62p,t=.39#},-t]&,{p=(-1)^(.4Range@5)},#]&
```

[image]